# Wordpress blog + Google AdSense

Tags: wordpress, google-ads-api

These days i am writing something in my blog. so yesterday i submitted it to GoogleAdSense. they approved my account. upto this very good.

But, if i paste the html/javascript code in my post content wordpress is removing it. is there a way to display ads in my wordpress blog..:((

my blog is http://nareshbojja.wordpress.com

thanks
Naresh

Comment: If you hosted the blog on a non- wordpress.com server you can embed the adsense code into the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress.org removes JavaScript and other potentially malicious code. There are [lots of AdSense plugins for WordPress](http://www.quickonlinetips.com/archives/2006/11/10-best-wordpress-plugins-for-google-adsense/) that will automatically insert the Google AdSense ad positions for you.

**edit:** You [**cannot** put AdSense on a WordPress.*com* hosted blog](http://support.wordpress.com/advertising/).

Comment: but my blog is hosted on wordpress. i am not hosting my blog. so is it possible to add plugins to default wordpress blog..

Comment: See my edit. Short answer: no.